# Eevee film grain type filter?

Tags: effects, eevee-render-engine

I have been searching on Google if there is any scratches/film grain type filter for Eevee while in realtime? Is this kind of filter even possible in Eevee. I have seen it done in game engines. Or would I just have to render the scene and do it in post production as I normally do.

Thanks, James.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to emulate film grain without the compositor.

This is obviously a crude workaround, but you could find a film grain image sequence or video, (or somehow make one procedurally using nodes), and use it as an alpha texture for a plane. Then, constrain the plane's rotation and location to always be right in front of the camera. This wouldn't work if you need Depth of Field, but it would probably work ok if you didn't use DoF.

Comment: Thanks thats a good idea, I will try it.